# trigger in mysql inserts multiple rows instead of one

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-5.7

I am trying to insert the sum of 4 columns coming from 4 different tables in a separate table's (named `bugs`) trigger as follows:

```
SELECT 
    uat_reopened_stats.release_name,
    (uat_reopened_stats.rate_bugs + qa_reopened_stats.rate_bugs + closed_reopened_stats.rate_bugs + done_reopened_stats.rate_bugs)
INTO @releasename, @bugstotalreopenrate  
FROM qa_reopened_stats
JOIN uat_reopened_stats 
    ON qa_reopened_stats.release_name = uat_reopened_stats.release_name
JOIN closed_reopened_stats 
    ON closed_reopened_stats.release_name = uat_reopened_stats.release_name
JOIN done_reopened_stats 
    ON done_reopened_stats.release_name = uat_reopened_stats.release_name;

INSERT INTO release_stats (release_name, bugs_total_reopen_rate)
VALUES (@releasename, @bugstotalreopenrate)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    release_name=@releasename,
    bugs_total_reopen_rate=@bugstotalreopenrate;
END
```

However, when the trigger is executed (and having the `release_stats` table empty beforehand, I end up with the later having 11 (!) rows!

```
MySQL [jira_statistics]> select * from release_stats;
+--------------+------------------------+
| release_name | bugs_total_reopen_rate |
+--------------+------------------------+
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
| 2.3.0        | 9.090909004211426      |
+--------------+------------------------+
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the problem went away after setting `release_name` as primary key on the table `release_stats`.